# Время удержания клавиши

Tags: python, клавиатура

Делаю программу, которая требует отслеживать время удержания определённой клавиши, но мыслей на реализацию подобного нет. Подскажите модуль, функцию или готовое решение этой задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов много. Самый "чистый" - использование библиотеки https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/
которая имеет функции для работы с событиями клавиатуры. Дальше - замерять время нажатия и  отпускания нужной клавиши о определить продолжительность интервала нажатия  - дело техники.

Имеется также библиотека pynput c модулем keyboard,(https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) который позволяет делать примерно то-же.

Кроме того, в pygame вроде-бы были соответствующие функции. Можно поискать.